# Rest API $expand

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2010, odata

I am trying to use the REST API $expand and $filter on my list but the filter does not work.

I have 2 lists called **TicketType** and **TicketingSytem**. There is a parent child relationship between the two.  "TicketingSystem" is the parent and "TicketType" is the child.
When I perform the following rest, the columns from my child list show but, it does not filter.

Any ideas?

```
http://isaac.issharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/TicketingSystem?$expand=TicketType&?$filter=TicketType/ID eq 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `?` in the URL - it separates the path from the query string, try it like this:

http://isaac.issharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/TicketingSystem?$expand=TicketType&$filter=TicketType/ID eq 10

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use $filer in $expand should be http://isaac.issharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/TicketingSystem?$expand=TicketType($filter=TicketType/ID eq 10). This is described in [OData spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793689)